# How to store missmatching rows from two files to a new file

Tags: linux, awk

I have two input files as follows And I need to write the mismatching rows from second file to a new file.Each column in the file is separated by a tab space

Input 1

```
1       94564350        .       C       A
1       94564350        .       C       T
```

Input 2

```
1       94564351        .       A       T
1       94564351        .       A       C
1       94564350        .       C       A
```

and the Output is

```
1       94564351        .       A       T
1       94564351        .       A       C
```

I have tried this command

```
awk -F"\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}($2 in a)&& $1>=3' fileB fileA >fileC
```

but not working.

```
awk 'NR == FNR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)'  fileA fileB
```

above command also taking too much time for big files is there any other options to do the same

Comment: I have tried this command awk -F"\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}($2 in a)&& $1>=3' fileB fileA >fileC but not working

Comment: What does “mismatched” mean?

Comment: Miss-match in the second column in the above file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this taken from [Idiomatic awk](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/):

```
awk 'NR == FNR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)'  fileA fileB
```

You don't need to assign `-F="\t"`, awk interprets it properly on files like these.

#### Test

```
$ awk 'NR == FNR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)'  fileA fileB
1       94564351        .       A       T
1       94564351        .       A       C
```